# Align Two Paragraphs in One Line

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm using MigraDoc to create PDF file. I'm adding two paragraph in a textframe. One paragraph is a label while the other is a textbox. After adding the paragraphs to textframe I added the textframe to table row cell. Currently the textbox location goes below the label. I want it to be just beside the label or they are just in one line. Anyone knows the solution for this? Please help. Here's my code and image

**Code:**

```
 static void AddTextBlockAndTextBoxToRow(Row row, int cellIndex, Paragraph label, Paragraph textbox)
        {
            var textFrame = new TextFrame();
            label.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
            textbox.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
            textFrame.Add(label);
            textFrame.Add(textbox);
            row.Cells[cellIndex].Add(textFrame);
        }
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: You should take two TextFrame for each label and Textbox and add individually into row..this will work

Comment: @KumodSingh I tried to add each to separate textframes but the output is even farther.

Comment: Thanks @Kumod Singh. Solution was posted here http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2696

Comment: Great! Comments, that link to a forum that links back to the **same** SO question as answer! This will cause a **Stack Overflow**

Answer (score 4):

MigraDoc cannot easily show two paragraphs side by side. Not in one table cell, not in one TextFrame.

You could create a table with two columns inside your TextFrame to work around this limitation.

Or do it without TextFrame and create two cells in the main table (you can use MergeRight for other rows to merge those two cells in other rows).

Comment: This answer is wrong. Paraphs can added to same row using negative SpaceBefore values. I added correct answer with sample code.

Comment: @Andrus Can we agree that answer is no longer wrong?

Comment: According to answer it is not possible to align two paragraphs in one TextFrame. If code from my answer is used to add two paragraphs to textframe, this is possible.

Comment: @Andrus My answer admits that it is is possible, but it is not easy. With variable text it quickly gets frigging complicated or even impossible.  Setting `Format.SpaceBefore = "-0.8cm"` is not the universal answer to get two-column text layouts, it is just a hack for demonstration purposes. It will help in some cases though.

Answer (score 1):

Sample table program in pdfsharp....

```
Table table = document.LastSection.AddTable();
table.Borders.Visible = true;
table.Format.Shading.Color = Colors.LavenderBlush;
table.Shading.Color = Colors.Salmon;
table.TopPadding = 5;
table.BottomPadding = 5;

Column column = table.AddColumn();
column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

column = table.AddColumn();
column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

column = table.AddColumn();
column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

table.Rows.Height = 35;

Row row = table.AddRow();
row.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Text");
row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("Text");
row.Cells[2].AddParagraph("Text");

row = table.AddRow();
row.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Text");
row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("Text");
row.Cells[2].AddParagraph("Text");

row = table.AddRow();
row.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Text");
row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("Text");
row.Cells[2].AddParagraph("Text");
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but I think this is not the output that I'm looking for. As you have noticed in my code two paragraphs, one label and one textbox, are added to the same cell index. I have issue with textbox since it goes down below the label.

Comment: Frined, don't add two element in same cell thats why U got that problem. so try to put those controls in different cell in same row.

Answer (score -1):

Highest score answer is wrong. Paragraphs can paced to same row using negative SpaceBefore value with LeftIndent:

```
    var document = new Document { };
    var section = document.AddSection();
    section.AddParagraph("paragraph1" + Environment.NewLine + "second line");
    var par2 = section.AddParagraph("paragraph2");
    par2.Format.LeftIndent = "4cm";
    par2.Format.SpaceBefore = "-0.8cm";
    return document;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: OK, proof of concept works. But it quickly gets complicated when you have variable text in both paragraphs. You must also set `RightIndent` for first paragraph, the value for `SpaceBefore` must be determined based on the contents of the first paragraph, you must ensure there is no page break between the two paragraphs.

Comment: Paragraphs are not exactly on the same row, the left paragraph is a bit higher than the right paragraph. Instead of using "0.8cm" one would have to calculate the correct value for the height of two lines plus the line spacing. 8 mm are 22.68 points where the correct value could be 23 or 24 points or so.